# Window Phone 8: How to read files from SavedPictures folder into a byte buffer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, photolibrary

How can we use Pictures/RootPictureAlbum/SavedPicture API of MediaLibrary class to access the photos in SavedPicture folder to read them into byte buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by this way

```
        using (var library = new MediaLibrary())
        {

            var savedPictures = library.Pictures.ToList();
            if (savedPictures.Any())
            {
                foreach (var pic in savedPictures)
                {
                    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height);
                    using (var stream = pic.GetImage()) //here you will get the stream
                    {

                        bitmap.SetSource(stream);                           

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Asitis it worked.Previously I've saved a picture into CameraRoll and with the above code I was able to retrieve the picture, but now the problem is while saving and retrieving, the buffer size is totally different, What would be the possible reason for this?

Comment: What is the buffer size difference you mean?

Comment: I've converted stream to byte array before saving and also after retrieving, the length of these byte arrays is different?

Comment: If you want to get the exact image use pic.GetImage() instead of pic.GetThumbnail()

Comment: I've used GetImage() only. I just wanted to know how the size of the image is increasing after saving it to the camera roll.

Comment: add it in your question , so that others can understand your problem easily.

Comment: My problem got solved. It was the problem of file format. I was saving the file in different format, that is why it showed different file sizes.